# Problems with Encrypted Files

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption, bsod, efs

I was having problems with my main drive and decided to upgrade to a new SSD for my boot drive. Upon installing Windows I realized I could not access any of my encrypted files due to not having that certificate.

My next plan of action was to just boot into my old OS and decrypt the files but it just BSOD with "Critical driver nvstor.sys is missing or contains errors.". I've searched the error and haven't found any working solutions yet.

Is there any way to retrieve the certificate offline on a different Windows installation? Or do I have to fix this BSOD error somehow to regain access to my encrypted files?

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have the password or the certificate, or whichever means were used to decrypt the files normally, you cannot decrypt files.

Any other methods would be big holes allowing attackers to gain access to the files.

In order to be secure, encryption systems must also be strict.

Comment: Well, I guess I got to figure out what's going on with this drive. I've ran sfc and it came back with this: https://pastebin.com/HzpSq1jU

Comment: Looks like you have another question. You can mark my answer here as the correct answer for this question, then use the Ask Question button to ask a question about repairing the drive.

Comment: Is it possible to boot into recovery DVD and export the cipher cert?

Comment: If the cert is a file, then any method of accessing the drive should allow you to get to the file.

Comment: It's not unfortunately, I would need to export it to a pfx file